# How to create a contact using Business Central API 2.0?

Tags: odata, dynamics-business-central

(NOTE: The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/business-central/dev-itpro/api-reference/v2.0/api/dynamics_contact_create) mentioned below is wrong at the time of this submission. It looks like it was copied from a template and not changed. I've submitted comment on Microsoft's GitHub page.)

Has anyone had success creating a contact using the Business Central v2 API? I'm following the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/business-central/dev-itpro/api-reference/v2.0/api/dynamics_contact_create) and not having any success. Updates work great, but I can't get create requests working at all.

The documentation says I should be able to post to the contacts end-point like so,

`POST businesscentralPrefix/companies({id})/contacts({id})`

The fact that `{id}` is used as a placeholder for both `companies` and `contacts` URL components is strange and not at all what I would expect. A more complete example is also given on that page:

```html
POST https://{businesscentralPrefix}/api/v2.0/companies({id})/contacts({id})
Content-type: application/json
{
    "id" : "5d115c9c-44e3-ea11-bb43-000d3a2feca1",
    "number" : "108001",
    "type" : "Company",
    "displayName": "CRONUS USA, Inc.",
    "companyNumber" : "17806",
    "companyName" : "CRONUS US",
    "businessRelation" : "Vendor",
    "addressLine1": "7122 South Ashford Street",
    "addressLine2": "Westminster",
    "city": "Atlanta",
    "state": "GA",
    "country": "US",
    "postalCode": "31772",
    "phoneNumber": "+1 425 555 0100",
    "mobilePhoneNumber" : "",
    "email" : "ah@contoso.com",
    "website" : "",
    "searchName" : "",
    "privacyBlocked" : true,
    "lastInteractionDate" : "2021-06-01",
    "lastModifiedDateTime" : "2021-06-01"
}
```

The example has an `id` property in the payload, which doesn't seem like something I should be creating. Again the `id` here is confusing given the duplicate `{id}` placeholders in the URL.

Additionally, there are some header requirements that don't make sense for a create request:

> **If-Match**  Required. When this request header is included and the eTag provided does not match the current tag on the contact, the contact will not be updated.

I won't have an etag if I'm creating a contact, so that header doesn't seem to apply to create requests. If that's the case, then probably can't rely much on the documentation. If *that's* the case, then I can't help but wonder if the create end-point shouldn't be:

`POST https://{businesscentralPrefix}/api/v2.0/companies({company-guid})/contacts`

which seems more consistent with other REST APIs I've encountered, but leaves me wondering whether or not I need supply the `id` for the new contact? I'm going with "no", but Microsoft's documentation doesn't mention it outside of the examples.

I have no problems **updating** an existing contact. I'm left with three options for creating one:

1. `POST https://{businesscentralPrefix}/api/v2.0/companies({company-guid})/contacts({company-guid})`

   This one is what the docs imply, but it doesn't make any sense given that you're effectively filtering the contacts table by a company id. I gave it a shot just for the sake of it

```html
POST https://{businesscentralPrefix}/api/v2.0/companies({company-guid})/contacts({company-guid})
{
    "id":"8adc4ec5-8393-44ac-8860-fadd9e3603cb",
    "number": "TEST123",
    "displayName": "Another Test Contact",
    "type": "Person",
    ...
}
...
Response (with and without the contact guid in payload)
{
    "error": {
        "code": "BadRequest_MethodNotAllowed",
        "message": "'POST' requests for 'contacts' of EdmType 'Entity' are not allowed within Dynamics 365 Business Central OData web services.  CorrelationId:  XXX"
    }
}
```

2. `POST https://{businesscentralPrefix}/api/v2.0/companies({company-guid})/contacts({contact-guid})`

   this one also seems weird since it doesn't seem like I should be creating the record's id. Also tried it just to try it:

```html
POST https://api.businesscentral.dynamics.com/v2.0/{tenent-guid}/{environment}/api/v2.0/companies({company-guid})/contacts(8adc4ec5-8393-44ac-8860-fadd9e3603cb)
{
    "id":"8adc4ec5-8393-44ac-8860-fadd9e3603cb",
    "number": "TEST123",
    "displayName": "Another Test Contact",
    "type": "Person",
    ...
}
...
Response (with and without the contact id guid in payload)
{
    "error": {
        "code": "BadRequest_MethodNotAllowed",
        "message": "'POST' requests for 'contacts' of EdmType 'Entity' are not allowed within Dynamics 365 Business Central OData web services.  CorrelationId:  XXXX."
    }
}
```

3. `POST https://{businesscentralPrefix}/api/v2.0/companies({company-guid})/contacts`

   Number 3 makes sense in my mind but fails with

```html
POST https://api.businesscentral.dynamics.com/v2.0/{tenent-guid}/{environment}/api/v2.0/companies({company-guid})/contacts(8adc4ec5-8393-44ac-8860-fadd9e3603cb)

{
    "id":"8adc4ec5-8393-44ac-8860-fadd9e3603cb",
    "number": "TEST123",
    "displayName": "Another Test Contact",
    "type": "Person",
    ...
}
...
Response (with and without the contact id guid in payload)
{
    "error": {
        "code": "Internal_RecordNotFound",
        "message": "The Contact does not exist. Identification fields and values: No.='TEST123'  CorrelationId:  XXX."
    }
}
```

Has anyone had success creating a contact using the Business Central v2 API? If so, how did you do it and what am I doing wrong? Also, the system I'm working with was upgrade from a local NAV instance, fwiw.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error seems to occur when both `number` and `type` is included in the payload.

The solution would be to create the contact without either `number` or `type` and then update the value you left out with a patch request.

Comment: I think you might be right. I pulled out the number and the submit went through. The implementation I'm working with pulls the next number value from a different table, and previously (on premises NAV) that table had to be manually updated after every new record created. I thought the API might be the same, but it looks instead like that's already handled by the backend.